# SSIS Data Conversion Failure. Potential Loss of Data when importing field with all "00000000" into a character field

Tags: sql-server, ssis, flat-file

I am trying to import data from a flat file into an SQL database. The data has been all stored as text and is giving an error when it gets to the first row of the D_FST_ADM field.  This data is as follows "00000000".  It does not have quotes around it in the file.

[image: This is a sample image of my data]

The errors I am getting are this:

> [Flat File Source [240]] Error: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "D_FST_ADM" returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".
> [Flat File Source [240]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Flat File Source.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[D_FST_ADM]" failed because error code 0xC0209084 occurred, and the error row disposition on "Flat File Source.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[D_FST_ADM]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Flat File Source returned error code 0xC0202092.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

I have tried changing the field in the database from a date field to an integer and then to character, with no luck.

I tried to create a derived field for it but with no success either.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error *is* telling you the problem here; what ever the data type the data is going into in the `Flat File Source` step (not the destination), is not suitable for the sample data.

Comment: To add, the problem column is specifically `D_FST_ADM`, as the error is also telling you. I suspect your column's definition, in the flat file source is not wide enough or you're converting it to a numerical data type that isn't large enough.

Comment: Looking at the other data in the column, looks like a date datatype. You may have to convert the 0's to a valid date or NULL.

Comment: I ended up setting both the input and output columns as characters.  This has worked.